# How to Open Whatsapp app from other app with a specific contact in ionic 3?

Tags: android, android-intent, ionic3, ionic-native, ionic-plugins

I've developed an ionic 3 app. I am unable to open whatsapp from my app with a specific contact in ionic 3. i don't want to send or share any thing but only wants to open whatsapp in android & iOS from my app with a specific contact. Is there any way to open whatsapp?
Till now i have implemented as below which is not working

```
window.open(`whatsapp:${+911234567890}`, '_system');
```

Any help much appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See it:
http://phonegap-plugins.com/plugins/ranjitpandit/whatsapp-phonegap-plugin

cordova.plugins.Whatsapp.send("yourNumber", sucessoCallback, errorCallback);

Answer (score 0):

I am Using this:

```
            String phone = "+8801510101010";

            PackageManager packageManager = MainActivity.this.getPackageManager();
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

            try {
                String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+ phone;
                i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                if (i.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```